# Importing two repositories with the same package name

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, dependencies, jupyter

I have an issue where I have two git repositories (`AdaBins`,`BLIP`) that have the same package name `models` that I'm trying to import and use in the same run. It appears that when I import one of the packages, the namespace gets locked, preventing me from using functions from the same package.

[image]
[image]

`AdaBins.infer` ends up calling a function that uses the `init.py` file inside `BLIP` instead of `AdaBins`, which is how it normally works.

[image]

I can fix it if I rename one of the packages to something else other than `models` and update all the `from models` in the repo, but obviously I'd prefer not to modify an outside dependency. I know this is somewhat anti-python but other than renaming the models, I'm just not too sure what to do, or how to properly do it.

Here is the file-structure:

```
- disco-investigator.ipynb
  - BLIP
    - models
      - __init__.py
      - blip.py
  - AdaBins
    - models
      - __init__.py
      - unet_adaptive_bins.py
```

I've tried the whole `sys.path.append`, `sys.path.remove`, `del sys.modules` for each package, but it doesn't seem to resolve my issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but solved it with the axe. I forked and refactored that folder. I did fork it quite some time ago already and it never changed until now so I hope it is kinda stable for quite some time. But now I can use it aside from Blip. if you like feel free to use my fork https://github.com/osi1880vr/AdaBins